# How to solve joi regex must be a RegExp errror

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, joi

I am trying to validate an input value with joi regex function, but I keep getting the following error: 'regex must be a RegExp'

Below is the joi schema and a screenshot of the thrown error. Your help will be most appreciated

```js
const nameSchema = () => {
  const exp = /^[\w'\-,.][^0-9_¡?÷?¿/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$/
  const name = Joi.string()
    .trim()
    .required()
    .max(50)
    .regex(exp)
    .lowercase()
    .error(errors => formatError(errors))
  return { firstname: name, lastname: name }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSBRx.png)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code causing the error? Try commenting out the line `.regex(exp)` and check that the error goes away. Then reintroduce the line to check it comes back.

Comment: Thanks Skirtle. I have done what you suggested couple of times and the error is coming from regex(exp).

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596779/joi-regex-is-not-recognized-as-regex-pattern

Comment: Thank your response, @a1300. However, I have tried your recommendation and it's throwing the same error. I even copied exactly the solution just to ensure nothing is missing yet the error won't go away.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue here. Just for debugging this: Do you also use this within `NuxtJS`? Ah yes, I just saw it in your tags. I suppose that Nuxt has some issues with this and it especially related to the Nuxt store. I use these validations within the store and get the same error, even if I use `pattern()` examples from the `Joi` documentation.

Comment: `Nuxt` stringifies the state and therefore can't store functions in the state, and probably does something with the `actions` as well, although I was able to use function references there. Patterns seem to be an issue with Nuxt.

Comment: I was having the same problem in Nuxt but just realized it happens only when I define the validation that uses regex and is placed inside a computed property. Moving the validation to a method  and running it from the computed property solve the issues.